# Changing CSS with d3.transition()

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I am using D3 transitions to rotate text, but am running into a strange problem. When rotating from 0 to -90 degrees, the transition works as expected. However, when transitioning from -90 degrees to 0 the transition does not work. An example can be seen here - http://jsfiddle.net/t7MRa/. The code to transition to 0 degrees is:

```
d3.selectAll("h2")
   .transition().duration(1000)
   .style("-webkit-transform", "rotate(0deg)");
```

I have tried `.style("-webkit-transform", "none")` which did not work. Any tips on what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Whats makes u say it does not rotate?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear. It does rotate back to 0 degrees, but there is no animation like there is when rotating from 0 to -90 degrees.

Answer (score 3):

D3 uses `getComputedStyle` to determine the starting value for transitions. Unfortunately, `getComputedStyle` for CSS transforms returns the transform matrix, not the transform string you specified.  So, the starting point for the reverse transition looks something like this:

```
matrix(0, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0)
```

(I'm not actually sure why the first transition works. The transform matrix value when there is no transform on the element is "matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)" and somehow the string interpolator is able to do something with that but I don't know why.)

To work around this, you have a few options:

1. If your start and end points are well-defined (as they are in the example) you could create a [custom tween](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions#wiki-styleTween) that runs [interpolateString](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions#wiki-d3_interpolateString) yourself passing in the known start and end transforms based on the current state of the rotation as "rotate" strings.
2. You could convert your "rotate" string to a transform matrix and pass that in to `transition.style` instead. The MDN article on [CSS transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) says that `rotate(angle)` is equivalent to `[cos(angle) sin(angle) -sin(angle) cos(angle) 0 0]`.
3. You could switch to using SVG with a `text` element.  SVG transforms are well understood by d3 and will work in most cases (your examples being one) without special handling on your part.

I did find a [bug report pertaining to Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=732153) where there is some discussion about changing this, but considering the same behavior appears in both Firefox and WebKit it seems like we'll be living with this behavior for a while.

Comment: all the transitions "work", but always begin at rotate(0deg). If you change the second transition to go to -20deg, for instance, you will see that. I did try also the matrix alternative, but it doesn't work. (It won't do anything, looks like an internal error in d3)

Comment: It works for me if I use matrix (http://jsfiddle.net/62tTD/) but the results from a default string interpolation are not very satisfactory.  I think using matrix you'd need to recalculate the angles at each step in the transition to get it to look perfect.  You need a rotation-aware tween, which d3 provides automatically if you use SVG transform.